# javaps for windows

Tags: windows, linux, bash

I'm working on some scripts that use javaps ([Linux Java Process Status](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~akonstan/javaps/) ).

The majority of the development has been on linux, but now we need to switch to running them on Windows XP via GIT Bash and I get the following response.

```
$ javaps
/c/Documents and Settings/xxxx/bin/javaps: must be executed on Linux system (found MINGW32_NT-5.1)
```

Any ideas apart from not switching to windows.

Comment: can you not use jps which ships with the jdk?

Comment: Thanks jps works, it is less verbose that javaps but think we can alter the scripts to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware of JPS as suggested by Petesh and we can alter the scripts to work with this over javaps on Windows.

---

Playing with the arguments provides the information we require to be able to use it.